# How to get ContentReference Name

Tags: apex, richtextarea

I have attached some image in my custom field 'Rich Text Area'. Than i just want name of uploaded or attached image from Field.

Thanks In Adv.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that rich text area simply doesn't care about file name. Also I can see only one advantage of using this field - it's can display image at your page layout.

If I'm right, you can store your files in attachments and display them in your rich text.

In the following example trigger for attachment checks if its our sObject type and then updates custom fields with file name and file link:

```
trigger attachmentTrigger on Attachment (after update, after insert) {
string placeholder = '<img alt="{0}" src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={1}"></img>';
list<contact> contactToUpdate = new list<Contact>();

for (Attachment att :trigger.new) {
    if (att.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Schema.Contact.SObjectType){

        List<String> fillers = new String[]{att.name,string.valueOf(att.id)};
        contactToUpdate.add(new Contact(id = att.ParentId, 
                                        pname__c = att.name, 
                                        picture__c = String.format(placeholder, fillers)));
    }
}
update contactToUpdate;
}
```

You will see the latest image in you rich text. You can change it to readonly mode.

[image]